# Removing special characters from string

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing

I want to parse this string into a list and return {1.193493, 54.6333, 2.093077, 31.6235, 6.175355, 21.6479}. How do I get rid of the square brackets???? I used a for loop and replace but it doesn't work.

```
String st = "[[[1.193493,54.6333],[2.093077,31.6235],[6.175355,21.6479]]]"

String[] parsed = st.split(",");

for (String next : parsed) {
        next.replace("//[", "").replace("//]", "");
    }
```

Comment: Strings are **immutable**, so expect all methods that operate on strings seemingly modifying the String to return a new String instance, rather than modifying the string itself.

Answer (score 1):

[`replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) works with plain Strings, not regex. Therefore you can simply use:

```
next.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
```

Also notice that you need to assign it to some string variable; assigning it to `need` won't work (won't modify elements in `parsed` array).

You should actually remove the braces first and `split` later, like this:

```
String[] parsed = st.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with one line:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(t.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").split(","));
```

Full code:

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Demo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String t = "[[[1.193493,54.6333],[2.093077,31.6235],[6.175355,21.6479]]]";

        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(t.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").split(","));
        for(String s : list)
        {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Converts string to list of strings and prints it. If you need to convert strings to doubles, use `Double.parseDouble(s)` in loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all at one time with [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/nB9wC7/4):

```
(?:\D*(\d*\.\d*))+
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve your goal in two steps.

1) Remove all special characters except comma (,)

2) Then split by comma (,)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    String st = "[[[1.193493,54.6333],[2.093077,31.6235],[6.175355,21.6479]]]";
    String[] parsed = st.replaceAll("[^\\d.,]+", "").split(",");    
}
```

Output:

[image]